# Как обернуть название своих полей в html теги?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

```
 public function get_formatted_billing_address() {
    if ( ! $this->formatted_billing_address ) {

        // Formatted Addresses.
        $address =  array(
            'first_name'    => 'ФИО: '.$this->billing_first_name,
            'last_name'     => ''.$this->billing_last_name,
            'company'       => $this->billing_company,
            'address_1'     => 'Район: '.$this->billing_address_1,
            'address_2'     => $this->billing_address_2,
            'city'          => 'Населенный пункт: '.$this->billing_city,
            'state'         => 'Область: '.$this->billing_state,
            'postcode'      => 'Индекс: '.$this->billing_postcode,
            'country'       => $this->billing_country
        );

        $this->formatted_billing_address = WC()->countries->get_formatted_address( $address );
    }

    return $this->formatted_billing_address;
}
```

Добавил свои названия для полей, хочется чтобы они выделялись через html тег b , но вордпресс их выводит как текст.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В php этого не сделать. Для этих целей есть css. Добавьте в style.css своей темы

```
input#billing_first_name {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

для поля first_name. Для остальных полей - аналогично.